# DropDown oculto al tener muchos items

Tags: javascript, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, devexpress

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web en asp net mvc, tengo un navbar con Bootstrap 4 y tengo muchos dropdown, pero en el menú aparecen ocultos varios dropdown

Este es el codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>ContaSoft</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/notify.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    @* Uncomment to use the HtmlEditor control *@
    @* <script src="https://unpkg.com/devextreme-quill/dist/dx-quill.min.js"></script> *@

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bundle")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/DevExtremeBundle")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bundle")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DevExtremeBundle")

</head>

<body style="padding-top: 5rem;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-md">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="~/Empresa/Index">@Session["Empresa"]</a>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Contabilidad
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroConta/Index">Maestro Contable</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/Ptda_Enc_Ds/Index">Partidas Contables</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configurar Reportes Financieros</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reporte Estadisticos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Balance Comprobacion</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Balance Saldos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Libro Mayor Auxiliar</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes Financieros</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Cierres</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Bancos
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroBancos/Index">Maestro Bancos</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Chequeras</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Historial Cambiario</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Conciliaciones Bancarias</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Estado Cuenta Bancos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reporte Diario Bancos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Listar Movimientos Bancarios</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configurar Modulo</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Cierres</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Cuentas x Cobrar
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroCxCobrar/Index">Maestro Clientes</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Clientes</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Cierres</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Cuentas x Pagar
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Maestro Proveedores</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Proveedores</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Cierres</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Inventario
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroINV/Index">Maestro Inventario</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroBodega/Index">Maestro Bodega Otros</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Maestro Ubicaciones</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Requisiciones Inventario</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Traslado Inventario</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Devolucion Requisicion</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ajuste Inventario</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Toma Fisica Inventario</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Productos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reporte Existencias</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Puntos Reorden</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reporte General Inventarios</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Actualizar Saldo Inventario</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Actualizar Utilidad Inventario</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Cierres</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Facturacion
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroFact/Index">Maestro Facturacion</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Cotizaciones</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/Mov_Enc_D_Facts/Index">Movimiento Facturacion</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Devoluciones</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Consulta Precios y Existencias</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Compras
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Solicitudes Compra</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Solicitud Cotizacion</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Control Cotizacion</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ordenes Compra</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Compras</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Devolucion Compras</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reporte Movimientos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Libro Compras</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Caja
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroCaja/Index">Maestro Caja Chica</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Arqueo Reembolso</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reembolso Caja Chica</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Caja Chica</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Registrar Pago Clientes</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimientos Caja</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Arqueo Caja</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Nomina/Planilla
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Maestro Empleados</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Percepciones/Deducciones</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Crear/Preparar Planilla</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Calcular Planilla</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Activos Fijos
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Compras</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Anticipo Clientes
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Anticipos</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Anticipo Proveedores
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Anticipos</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Cartera Bancos
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Clientes</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Taller
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Maestro Taller</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Orden Trabajo</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Requisiciones</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Seguridad
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Usuarios</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accesos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Perfiles</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">@Session["Usuario"]</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Esta es la imagen de la pantalla con el menú de Bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es una aplicacion ERP con varios modulos, por eso añadi varios dropdown, pero no aparecen los demas y necesito que el usuario los pueda visualizar por medio de un scroll y que el menu del dropdown se pueda ver encima del scroll. necesito saber como hacer para que los otros dropdown aparezcan, estoy usando Bootstrap 4 y visual studio 2019. No tengo ningun css en la aplicacion web.

Comment: No hay una forma en que puedas categorizar cada opción con sus respectivos submenús? Tener un header o sidebar con tanto dropdown... uff... complejo :(

Comment: Si no puedes reagrupar los menús, entonces convendría un cambio de diseño, poner el menú vertical y, probablemente, oculto para mostrar cuando se haga clic o se pase el mouse sobre otro elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregango la clase "nav" en el ul:

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto nav">
```

Ver el ejemplo en pantalla completa:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body style="padding-top: 5rem;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top navbar-expand-md">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="~/Empresa/Index">@Session["Empresa"]</a>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Contabilidad
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroConta/Index">Maestro Contable</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/Ptda_Enc_Ds/Index">Partidas Contables</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configurar Reportes Financieros</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reporte Estadisticos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Balance Comprobacion</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Balance Saldos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Libro Mayor Auxiliar</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes Financieros</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Cierres</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Bancos
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroBancos/Index">Maestro Bancos</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Chequeras</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Historial Cambiario</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Conciliaciones Bancarias</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Estado Cuenta Bancos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reporte Diario Bancos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Listar Movimientos Bancarios</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configurar Modulo</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Cierres</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Cuentas x Cobrar
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroCxCobrar/Index">Maestro Clientes</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Clientes</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Cierres</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Cuentas x Pagar
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Maestro Proveedores</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Proveedores</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Cierres</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Inventario
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroINV/Index">Maestro Inventario</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroBodega/Index">Maestro Bodega Otros</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Maestro Ubicaciones</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Requisiciones Inventario</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Traslado Inventario</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Devolucion Requisicion</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ajuste Inventario</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Toma Fisica Inventario</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Productos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reporte Existencias</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Puntos Reorden</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reporte General Inventarios</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Actualizar Saldo Inventario</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Actualizar Utilidad Inventario</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Cierres</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Facturacion
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroFact/Index">Maestro Facturacion</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Cotizaciones</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/Mov_Enc_D_Facts/Index">Movimiento Facturacion</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Devoluciones</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Consulta Precios y Existencias</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Compras
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Solicitudes Compra</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Solicitud Cotizacion</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Control Cotizacion</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ordenes Compra</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Compras</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Devolucion Compras</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reporte Movimientos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Libro Compras</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Caja
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="~/MaestroCaja/Index">Maestro Caja Chica</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Arqueo Reembolso</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reembolso Caja Chica</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Caja Chica</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Registrar Pago Clientes</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimientos Caja</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Arqueo Caja</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Nomina/Planilla
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Maestro Empleados</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Percepciones/Deducciones</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Crear/Preparar Planilla</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Calcular Planilla</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Activos Fijos
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Compras</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Anticipo Clientes
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Anticipos</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Anticipo Proveedores
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Anticipos</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Cartera Bancos
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Movimiento Clientes</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reportes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Taller
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Maestro Taller</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Orden Trabajo</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Requisiciones</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Configuracion Modulo</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Seguridad
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Usuarios</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Accesos</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Perfiles</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">@Session["Usuario"]</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container">

    </main>



</body>
```